# How to add android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-developer-api, android-studio-3.6.1

I am using Android Studio ver. 3.6.2, and am following a tutorial to create a messaging application.

I could not find the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` when adding a new resource file in the root element. When I choose `android.widget.ToolBar` the `setSupportActionBar` got an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What error, specifically? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: The `android.support` classes are all deprecated, no longer receiving bug fixes or new features, and should not be used in new code.  You should [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```